My AWS lambda function is not working with Dynamo DB getItem using aws sdk version 3
I'm unable to get solution for basic dynamodb integration with aws lambda function using aws sdk version 3. Below is my index.mjs code.
    import { DynamoDBClient, GetItemCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb";
//import { marshall, unmarshall } from "@aws-sdk/util-dynamodb";
const dbclient = new DynamoDBClient({region:'us-east-1'});
export const handler = async (event) => {
  const uid=event.id;
  console.log("id from test event",uid);
  // TODO implement
  const params={
       TableName: 'test_cc_auth',
             Key: {
                 id: { S: uid }
                //id:  uid 
            }
          };
   // verify the db has data or not
     console.log("params object is ",params);
   var datafound;
   try{
      datafound= await dbclient.send(new GetItemCommand(params));
     console.log("data is : ",datafound);
   }catch(err){
      console.log(err);
   }
  const response = {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify(datafound),
  };
  return response;
};

I'm getting below error ."ValidationException: The provided key element does not match the schema", but when I modify code params object like id: uid then I'm getting "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')==== without mentioning S". Can some help how to figure this out and what is the difference between adding type S and with adding type. Thank you for your support.

Cannot be sure without knowing the schema of your table, but most likely the test_cc_auth table has both partition key and sort key. In this case you need to provide them both, i.e. something like this:
const params={
   TableName: 'test_cc_auth',
   Key: {
      id: { S: uid },
      other_id: { S: "value"}
   }
};

where other_id should be replaced by the name of your sort key.
Source: DynamoDB documentation

Doing a GetItem you need to provide the entire primary key, which is both the partition PK and the sort key SK. If you want to obtain data just related to the partition key, you need to issue a Query call. A Query will return a list of Items even if there is only a single item in the list:
import { DynamoDBClient, QueryCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb";

const dbclient = new DynamoDBClient({region:'us-east-1'});
export const handler = async (event) => {
  const uid=event.id;
  console.log("id from test event",uid);
  // TODO implement
  const params={
       TableName: 'test_cc_auth',
             KeyConditionExpression: "#id = :id",  
             ExpressionAttributeValues: {
                 ":id" : { S: uid }
             }, 
             ExpressionAttributeNames: {
                 "#id": "id":
             }
          };
   // verify the db has data or not
     console.log("params object is ",params);
   var datafound;
   try{
      datafound= await dbclient.send(new QueryCommand(params));
     console.log("data is : ",datafound);
   }catch(err){
      console.log(err);
   }
  const response = {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify(datafound),
  };
  return response;
};

If you know the sort key (should one be defined) then you can simply add that to your GetItem key. If you have not defined a sort key, then make sure the partition key of your table is id and its value is a String S.
